# Proper syntax for multiple table update in MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to verify the correct syntax to use to carry out an multiple table update in MySQL 5.5. I have two tables, the first is structured like this:

```
| *post_id* | lat | long |
```

where post_id is a unique identifier. The second table is a Wordpress postmeta table:

```
| *meta_id* | post_id | meta_key | meta_value |
```

where `meta_id` is a unique identifier. `Post_ID`s from the first table match the second table. Some of the `meta_keys` in the second table include `list-lat` and `list-long`.

I wish to update the values of `long` in the first table with the corresponding value from the second table where `long` is 0.000000 and `lat` is not 0.000000. The following select statement identifies 130 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM bch_postmeta
JOIN bch_coords ON bch_coords.post_id = bch_postmeta.post_id
WHERE bch_coords.long = 0.000000 
AND bch_coords.lat <> 0.000000 AND bch_postmeta.meta_key = 'list-long'
```

This is as expected. If I try a simple UPDATE and simulate it, I once again affect 130 rows:

```
UPDATE bch_coords
SET bch_coords.long = 0.0 
WHERE bch_coords.long = 0.000000 AND bch_coords.lat <> 0.000000
```

However, once I try to incorporate the second table, the query ceases to work. The following two queries both affect 0 rows. The second is of course the update I wish to carry out.

```
UPDATE bch_coords, bch_postmeta
SET bch_coords.long = 0.0 
WHERE bch_coords.long = 0.000000 AND bch_coords.lat <> 0.000000

UPDATE bch_coords, bch_postmeta
SET bch_coords.long = bch_postmeta.meta_value
WHERE bch_coords.post_id = bch_postmeta.post_id AND bch_postmeta.meta_key = 'list-long'
AND bch_coords.long = 0.000000 AND bch_coords.lat <> 0.000000
```

I have not used `ANSI` joins because they caused a failure of the query whenever used in an `UPDATE` for some reason (also a mystery at this point).

Can anyone shed some light on exactly what I've done wrong here?

I've created an SQLFiddle markdown below:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f951/1)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE bch_coords
    (`post_id` int, `lat` numeric, `long` numeric, UNIQUE(post_id))
;

INSERT INTO bch_coords
    (`post_id`, `lat`, `long`)
VALUES
    (1, 15.986132, 136.82515),
    (2, 0.000000, 0.000000),
    (3, -15.23850, 0.000000),
    (4, 136.32067, 0.000000),
    (5, -87.123567, 56.12396)
;


CREATE TABLE bch_postmeta
    (`meta_id` int, `post_id` int, `meta_key` varchar(13), `meta_value` varchar(15), UNIQUE(meta_id))
;

INSERT INTO bch_postmeta
    (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '''list-lat''', '15.986132'),
    (2, 1, '''list-long''', '136.82515'),
    (3, 1, '''country''', '''Switzerland'''),
    (4, 1, '''state''', '''Valais'''),
    (5, 2, '''list-lat''', '0.000000'),
    (6, 2, '''list-long''', '0.000000'),
    (7, 2, '''country''', '''Australia'''),
    (8, 3, '''list-lat''', '-15.00'),
    (9, 3, '''list-long''', '173.62198'),
    (10, 3, '''country''', '''USA'''),
    (11, 4, '''list-lat''', '136.32067'),
    (12, 4, '''list-long''', '5.123997'),
    (13, 5, '''list-lat''', '-88.125'),
    (14, 5, '''list-long''', '56.12396')
;
```

So, I have a data set that looks like this...

```
SELECT * FROM bch_coords;
+---------+------+------+
| post_id | lat  | long |
+---------+------+------+
|       1 |   16 |  137 |
|       2 |    0 |    0 |
|       3 |  -15 |    0 |
|       4 |  136 |    0 |
|       5 |  -87 |   56 |
+---------+------+------+

SELECT * FROM bch_postmeta;
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key    | meta_value    |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
|       1 |       1 | 'list-lat'  | 15.986132     |
|       2 |       1 | 'list-long' | 136.82515     |
|       3 |       1 | 'country'   | 'Switzerland' |
|       4 |       1 | 'state'     | 'Valais'      |
|       5 |       2 | 'list-lat'  | 0.000000      |
|       6 |       2 | 'list-long' | 0.000000      |
|       7 |       2 | 'country'   | 'Australia'   |
|       8 |       3 | 'list-lat'  | -15.00        |
|       9 |       3 | 'list-long' | 173.62198     |
|      10 |       3 | 'country'   | 'USA'         |
|      11 |       4 | 'list-lat'  | 136.32067     |
|      12 |       4 | 'list-long' | 5.123997      |
|      13 |       5 | 'list-lat'  | -88.125       |
|      14 |       5 | 'list-long' | 56.12396      |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

...and after the update, I want to have a data set that looks like this...

```
SELECT * FROM bch_coords;
+---------+------+------+
| post_id | lat  | long |
+---------+------+------+
|       1 |   16 |  137 |
|       2 |    0 |    0 |
|       3 |  -15 |  173 |
|       4 |  136 |  5.1 |
|       5 |  -87 |   56 |
+---------+------+------+
```

Comment: SQLFiddle may be found at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f951

Comment: The desired outcome is that the longitude values for post_id numbers 3 and 4 be copied from bch_postmeta to bch_coords. No other rows should be affected.

Comment: if mysql does not actually change the value of the field you are attempting to update then affected will be 0.  you are setting bch_coords.long = 0 where bch_coords.long = 0.  so there is no change there, no rows were affected

Comment: Two rows should be affected in the example - those which match post_id 3 and 4. Note that 0.0 is NOT equal to 0.000000 @KorreyD.

If I remove bch_postmeta from the UPDATE statement, the UPDATE affects 130 rows. As soon as I add bch_postmeta to the UPDATE statement, 0 rows are affected.

Comment: 0.0 is equal to 0.0000

Comment: My apologies - you are both correct. I was confused by the difference between a number of rows being matched and the number affected

Comment: Realising the above, I have double checked the following query:     _UPDATE bch_coords SET long = 0.000000001 WHERE long = 0 AND lat <> 0_ and found that it doesn't affect any rows (Simulate identifies 130 but the update doesn't actually affect any). I should probably redefine the question and start over - a simple update doesn't even work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
UPDATE bch_coords
SET bch_coords.long = (SELECT bch_postmeta.meta_value 
                       FROM bch_postmeta 
                       WHERE bch_postmeta.post_id = bch_coords.post_id
                       AND bch_postmeta.meta_key = 'list-long'
                       LIMIT 1)
WHERE bch_coords.long = 0.000000 
AND bch_coords.lat <> 0.000000
```

or this:

```
UPDATE bch_coords 
INNER JOIN bch_postmeta ON (bch_coords.post_id = bch_postmeta.post_id AND bch_postmeta.meta_key = 'list-long')
SET bch_coords.long = bch_postmeta.meta_value
WHERE bch_coords.long = 0.000000 
AND bch_coords.lat <> 0.000000
```

Comment: The first yields an error:

    _#1054 - Unknown column 'SELECTbch_postmeta.meta_value' in 'field list'._

 The second affects 0 rows. I had actually tried the second already although I included the meta_key restriction as part of the WHERE clause. Thank you for responding @David. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: in _'SELECTbch_postmeta.meta_value'_, i see no space between _SELECT_ and the _bch_postmeta.meta_value_. may be this is that cause the error

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, and more interesting than your actual question, it's sometimes forgotten that, if carefully constructed, a view can be used to update its underlying tables. Consider the following:

```
SELECT * FROM bch_postmeta;
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key    | meta_value    |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
|       1 |       1 | 'list-lat'  | 15.986132     |
|       2 |       1 | 'list-long' | 136.82515     |
|       3 |       1 | 'country'   | 'Switzerland' |
|       4 |       1 | 'state'     | 'Valais'      |
|       5 |       2 | 'list-lat'  | 0.000000      |
|       6 |       2 | 'list-long' | 0.000000      |
|       7 |       2 | 'country'   | 'Australia'   |
|       8 |       3 | 'list-lat'  | -15.00        |
|       9 |       3 | 'list-long' | 173.62198     |
|      10 |       3 | 'country'   | 'USA'         |
|      11 |       4 | 'list-lat'  | 136.32067     |
|      12 |       4 | 'list-long' | 5.123997      |
|      13 |       5 | 'list-lat'  | -88.125       |
|      14 |       5 | 'list-long' | 56.12396      |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+

CREATE VIEW v_bch_postmeta AS
SELECT a.post_id
     , a.meta_value list_lat
     , b.meta_value list_long
     , c.meta_value country
     , d.meta_value state
  FROM bch_postmeta a
  LEFT
  JOIN bch_postmeta b
    ON b.post_id = a.post_id
   AND b.meta_key = "'list-long'"
  LEFT
  JOIN bch_postmeta c
    ON c.post_id = a.post_id
   AND c.meta_key = "'country'"
  LEFT
  JOIN bch_postmeta d
    ON d.post_id = a.post_id
   AND d.meta_key = "'state'"
 WHERE a.meta_key = "'list-lat'";

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

SELECT * FROM v_bch_postmeta;
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+
| post_id | list_lat  | list_long | country       | state    |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+
|       1 | 15.986132 | 136.82515 | 'Switzerland' | 'Valais' |
|       2 | 0.000000  | 0.000000  | 'Australia'   | NULL     |
|       3 | -15.00    | 173.62198 | 'USA'         | NULL     |
|       4 | 136.32067 | 5.123997  | NULL          | NULL     |
|       5 | -88.125   | 56.12396  | NULL          | NULL     |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------------+----------+

UPDATE v_bch_postmeta SET list_lat = 1.0 WHERE post_id = 2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM bch_postmeta;
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
| meta_id | post_id | meta_key    | meta_value    |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
|       1 |       1 | 'list-lat'  | 15.986132     |
|       2 |       1 | 'list-long' | 136.82515     |
|       3 |       1 | 'country'   | 'Switzerland' |
|       4 |       1 | 'state'     | 'Valais'      |
|       5 |       2 | 'list-lat'  | 1.0           |
|       6 |       2 | 'list-long' | 0.000000      |
|       7 |       2 | 'country'   | 'Australia'   |
|       8 |       3 | 'list-lat'  | -15.00        |
|       9 |       3 | 'list-long' | 173.62198     |
|      10 |       3 | 'country'   | 'USA'         |
|      11 |       4 | 'list-lat'  | 136.32067     |
|      12 |       4 | 'list-long' | 5.123997      |
|      13 |       5 | 'list-lat'  | -88.125       |
|      14 |       5 | 'list-long' | 56.12396      |
+---------+---------+-------------+---------------+
```

This won't work for the NULL values in the view

Comment: This is an interesting and handy piece of information but fails to assist with my particular question.